# How to prevent the render of child components on the parent in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

Here I have created a toggle button re-rendering in parent components and in child components a plus button, and the counter requirement is that the toggle button re-rendering is a toggle button that will hide and show the components, but if any last counter is added, for example, from 0 to 2, after hiding and showing it should remain the same, like 2 and not 0, but the problem is that I am not able to hide the child components, so how do I hide and show the child components and maintain the child state?
Basically, by rendering the parent, I want to keep maintaining the child state value.
parent code is

```
import React, { useRef, useState, useMemo } from 'react';
import DropDown from './DropDown';

function App() {
  const shouldRenderChild = useRef(true);
  const [hide, setHide] = useState(false);

  const toggleChildRendering = () => {
    shouldRenderChild.current = !shouldRenderChild.current;
    setHide(!hide);
  };

  const MemoizedDropDown = useMemo(() => {
    return shouldRenderChild.current ? <DropDown /> : null;
  }, []);

  return (
    <div>
      <button onClick={toggleChildRendering}>
        Toggle Child Rendering
      </button>
      {MemoizedDropDown}
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

child code is

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
export default function DropDown() {
  const [number, setNumber] = useState(0);
  return (
    <>
      <button onClick={() => setNumber(number + 1)}>+</button>
      <div>Child Component{number}</div>
    </>
  );
}
```

Comment: state is reset if a component is unmounted and then remounted. If you want to keep state you need to simply hide the element, not unmount it.

Comment: how to hide without unmount state can you give some clue

Comment: Using useRef variable in that way in useMemo is a bad idea. To preserve the state of the child component - `hide` it with `css` instead of mounting/unmounting with conditional rendering.

Comment: so we have to write a hide class in the onclick of parent button?

Comment: Yes, if you want to keep the state in the child and maintain it through hiding you need to render it in the parent consistently, but just hide it with css. The alternative is to move the counter state to the parent and then conditionally render it, passing the state down.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Every time component is mounted or unmounted (using conditional rendering) - state of the component is re-setting itself to default values. So that is your problem, and `useMemo` hook will not help you here.

To solve your issue you can modify your root css files and add something like `.hidden` class:

```
.hidden {
  display: none;
}
```

Most probably you already have that kind of utility classes in your project. Like `d-none` for bootstrap or similar.

Next - you need to add a wrapper to your `DropDown` component, or change the type of root node that is returned by this component to something else than `React.Fragment` ie `<> </>` and to apply conditional `className` on it like this:

```
className={hide ? 'hidden' : ''}
```

Here is an example of the solution:

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';

function DropDown({ className }) {
  const [number, setNumber] = useState(0);
  return (
    <div className={className}>
      <button onClick={() => setNumber(number + 1)}>+</button>
      <div>Child Component: {number}</div>
    </div>
  );
}

export const App = () => {
  const [hide, setHide] = useState(false);

  const toggleChildRendering = () => {
    setHide(!hide);
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <button onClick={toggleChildRendering}>Toggle Child Rendering</button>
      <DropDown className={hide ? 'hidden' : ''} />
    </div>
  );
};
```

Stackblitz [demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-starter-typescript-cnzjjn?file=App.tsx)

Answer (score 0):

The simple solution to this is **Lifting the State up**.

1. Basically, if you're hiding a component with the condition `!hide ? <DropDown /> : null`, it'd be unmounted when `hide` is true.
2. Now, when you're storing the `number` in child's state, it would also be vanished.
3. So, if you store the `number` value in parent's state, it'd persist.
4. Now, if the child component gets unmounted due to the `hide` flag being true, you still got the **state saved in parent**.
5. This way,  you can hide/show the child component and the state would be preserved.
6. I would not suggest you to hide the component with CSS. But if it's a special use case for you then you can just use the `hide` flag for styling the child component to `display: none`

*<Dropdown style={{
display: hide ? 'none' : 'block'
}} ... />*

**The right way:**

App.js

```
function App() {
  const [number, setNumber] = useState(0);
  const [hide, setHide] = useState(false);
  ...
  return (
    ...
    <Dropdown number={number} changeNumber={setNumber} />
  )
}
```

Dropdown.js

```
export default function DropDown({number, changeNumber}) {
  return (
    <>
      <button onClick={() => changeNumber(number + 1)}>+</button>
      <div>Child Component{number}</div>
    </>
  );
}
```